# How to automatically authenticate users of a public website based on their remote Active Directory credentials

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory, azure-active-directory, federated-identity

So, I have a public website. I'd like to be able to have certain users automatically be authenticated (logged in) to the website based on their Active Directory credentials - so they don't have to enter in a username/password.

Those users - around the world - would be using computers that are part of their organization's Active Directory - and so, they would be already logged in to their computer as some AD User. I'd like to just, somehow, have a whitelist of those organizations (and maybe I'd need to like store their Active Directory "certificates" for cryptographic verification), and based on that and on their AD Username, they would be authenticated.

And maybe if, at the client computer he's using, the user isn't logged in as an AD user (because he's not at work or something), then it would be nice to like redirect him to some trusted website where he can enter in his AD credentials in order to login as the same website user. Know what I mean?

What are the best way(s) to do this?

I'm thinking some kind of Single Sign On thing, or Federated thing. I'm not sure what all is out there.

Comment: I think allow external services to connect to your AD to authenticate is a terrible practice. essentially as you've asked is very insecure. without security in place you are asking for a variety of potential attacks and issues.

Comment: According to your description, just looks like a user visit your public website and then  your website can know who he is. Is it legal? I mean how can your website get the credential without entering user information, by ip address?

Comment: Tiny: Well, I was hoping that someone out there knew of a way to do this. Maybe some kind of Single Sign On thing? or Federated thing? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The path of least resistance would be to Authenticate via Kerberos in IIS.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/ba-p/347882

Comment: Can this really work when the web server is not part of the client's Active Directory domain?

Comment: Yes, There are two options 1: Use local permissions e.g. <Username>@<localhost>  or 2: setup a Active Directory sub domain and add the web server to it.Also you could set up your web server as a Federated SSO server.